# Configuring Grafana Alerts for Website Downtime Based on Response Time and Failure Frequency

Tags: prometheus, grafana, monitoring, grafana-alerts

Hi Stack Overflow community,

I'm currently working on setting up monitoring and alerting for a website's availability using Grafana, and I need some guidance on how to configure alerts based on specific criteria. My goal is to create alerts that notify my team when:

The website's response time exceeds 5 seconds.
The website fails to respond successfully twice within a 5-minute window.

Here's what I've set up so far:

Data Source: I'm using Prometheus as my data source.
Query: I have a basic query that monitors the response time and status codes of the website but I'm unsure how to implement the above conditions in Grafana's alerting system.

Question:
How can I configure Grafana to trigger an alert if the website's response time is more than 5 seconds? I'm looking for details on the specific query expressions and the alert configuration settings.

Any insights, examples, or guidance on setting up these types of alerts in Grafana would be greatly appreciated. If there are any recommended practices or additional considerations for monitoring website availability effectively using Grafana, please share those as well.

Thank you in advance for your help!